# play ogg over mp4 in firefox only

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, html5-video

Because of firefox not playing my mp4, I made ogg files as remplacement. but it doesn't work as wanted because now, obviously, every other browser play .ogg by default

```
<video class='vid-bg' muted loop playsinline autoplay> 
 <source src='src/tata.ogg' poster='src/palm_bg.jpg' type='video/ogg'> 
 <source src='src/tata.mp4' poster='src/palm_bg.jpg' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

but the quality and the size of mp4 is better. So I inverted the ogg source tag and the mp4 one, but then firefox show blank content and stick on trying to load/read the mp4

I would like to say that if the browser can't read/load an mp4, it plays the ogg instead

(every chrome and edge and ie9+ reads my mp4 with no problems)

Comment: Firefox supports mp4 now - https://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4 - but if you're having problems you could test programatically using the `canPlayType` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType and choose the source that way. Also FYI, the `poster` attribute usually goes on the <video> element, not the <source> attribute.

Comment: If I go there with my fresh new install of firefox http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html I got nothing but a blank space right where the video is supposed to be

Comment: using current version of FF on macOS Catalina it works fine for me. what OS and browser versions are you trying?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal It doesn't really matter what os I am running, firefox read mp4 only if you have a codec that can read it. That is why it works for you.